# _wstat() always returns -1 on windows universal app

Tags: c++, windows, windows-phone, win-universal-app

[`_wstat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) function used to be able to get the status information of a file. In our Windows Universal App, we are using a third party library which uses `_wstat` function. We notice that the library doesn't function properly, and after debugging, we notice that it is `_wstat` fails to get the file info and always return ENOENT (-1) even for the files that is within the local folder of the app.

Is there any work around for this issue?

I want to make a patch for this library and I notice that there are functions such as [`File::GetAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp) do the similar thing of retrieving file information. But I don't think it is a good idea to go along this direction because this third party library is purely C++.